# Why does the VLOOKUP formula cause the HYPERLINK formula to not work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following information in Excel:

```
 Part Number           Part Name
199-102-002-B    Miniature Angle Mount Riser Block
199-102-092-C    Pinned Beamsplitter Mount
199-102-011-C    Camera Sleeve
199-102-032-D    1mm Aperture
199-102-081-D    VIS Attachment Plate
```

The part numbers can be used to look up the file location of the part, and I've created a function (`MyPath()`) that returns the path to the part's folder when given the part number.  I would like to enable the user to simply click on the text in the second column and have the folder for the part open.

Using the formula below, I can get the link to work properly, but the text is just the part number, not the part name:

```
=HYPERLINK(MyPath(A2),A2)
```

Using this formula, the part name shows up properly, and when I hover over the cell, my cursor changes to a hand like there is a hyperlink there, but clicking on it doesn't do anything.

```
=HYPERLINK(MyPath(A2),VLOOKUP(A2,PartsArray,2,FALSE))
```

Here are the other variations that I have tested that have worked:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\The\Path\To\The\Part\Folder","Miniature Angle Mount Riser Block")
=HYPERLINK(MyPath(A2),"Miniature Angle Mount Riser Block")
=HYPERLINK("C:\The\Path\To\The\Part\Folder",VLOOKUP(A2,PartsArray,2,FALSE))
=HYPERLINK(MyPath(A2),C2) <--- Where "C2" contains the VLOOKUP function
```

Only when I use both my custom function and the `VLOOKUP()` function together does the hyperlink stop working.

At this point, the closest thing I've found to a solution is what I did in the last variation shown above (i.e. moving the `VLOOKUP` portion of the formula to another column and then hiding that column). But there must be some explanation for this.  Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

## Edit:

The `VLOOKUP` function is referencing an array on a separate sheet that includes all the parts that will be used. The intention with this sheet is to enable someone in the assembly area to enter a part number and have the name of the part be shown in the adjacent cell.  I suppose I could recreate the `VLOOKUP` function by using the `MATCH` function (in combination with a few others), but I'd rather identify the real problem and fix that than blindly search for solutions that very likely won't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, the `HYPERLINK` function really doesn't like references to external workbooks that aren't also open (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1184055/hyperlink-not-working-when-referenced-external-workbook-is-closed) post for another example of when the function breaks).  The best solution I can come up with is therefore to move the references to external workbooks to another cell in the workbook. The only other option that I know of would be to create a macro that creates the hyperlink on the desired cell itself.  But that's not very convenient if you want to have many hyperlinks in a sheet, or if you don't know ahead of time where the text that needs to be hyperlinked is going to be.